# Texture Wrapping, Weird Edges

Tags: java, glsl, lwjgl

I'm currently experiencing an issue with my textured VBO at the point where the coordinates begin to wrap around. I added a 30px yellow border all the way around my texture to make the effect stand out more.
[image]

When looking at it closer, it looks almost as if the entire texture is squashed and smeared between the yellow lines.

[image]

Texture Coordinate Code (buffer[0] = vertex X, buffer[2] = vertex Y):

```
if ((buffer[0] * s) < 0) Logger.logDebug(buffer[8]+","+buffer[9]);
if ((buffer[2] * s) < 0) Logger.logDebug(buffer[8]+","+buffer[9]);
buffer[8] = (buffer[0] * s) % 1f; //tx
buffer[9] = (buffer[2] * s) % 1f; //ty
if (buffer[8] > 1f || buffer[9] > 1f) Logger.logDebug(buffer[8]+","+buffer[9]);
if (buffer[8] < 0f || buffer[9] < 0f) Logger.logDebug(buffer[8]+","+buffer[9]);
```

None of my checks for coordinates below 0 or above 1 passed, so they are in the right range.

Frag Shader:

```
#version 150 core

uniform sampler2D texture1;
in vec4 vColor;

in vec4 pass_Color;
in vec2 pass_texCoord;
out vec4 out_Color;

void main()
{
    out_Color = pass_Color;
    out_Color = texture(texture1, pass_texCoord.st);
}
```

Vert Shader:

```
uniform mat4 projection = mat4(
                        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
uniform mat4 view = mat4(
                        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                        1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
uniform vec4 overrideColor = vec4(-1,-1,-1,-1);

in vec4 in_Color;
in vec4 in_Position;
in vec2 texCoord;

out vec4 pass_Color;
out vec2 pass_texCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * gl_Vertex;
    if (overrideColor == vec4(-1,-1,-1,-1))
    {
        pass_Color = in_Color;
    }
    else
    {
        pass_Color = overrideColor;
    }
    pass_texCoord = texCoord;
}
```

Comment: That `%` looks suspicious. Can your coordinates be less than zero at that point? Try adding a few `fabs` here and there.

Comment: Is all of that one quad, or multiple with tex coords from [0,1]?

Comment: This is in Java, right?

Comment: I updated the question. I added checks before and after modding the coords. All coords were in the 0.0-1.0 range. Yes, this is Java, I just added that tag to specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a fine grid of quads and trying to wrap a large texture across them, right? I think that the problem is that some quads are spanning across the wrap boundary. You should either make sure that the wrap boundary occurs right on the edge of the quads, or as I would recommend, just set up your texture to wrap:

```
// when you set up your texture
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

Then **don't use modulus for the texture coordinates**; coords outside [0,1] will automatically wrap/repeat:

```
buffer[8] = buffer[0] * s; //tx
buffer[9] = buffer[2] * s; //ty
```

See [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62548/what-does-changing-gl-texture-wrap-s-t-do/62556) and [this](https://open.gl/textures) for what texture wrapping looks like.

Comment: Thanks. I just looked at my AssetManager and it was set to CLAMP_TO_EDGE rather than REPEAT. After changing that, and removing my modulus wrapping, the texture tiled properly.